# Can Silverlight play videos with transparency?

Tags: c#, video, silverlight-3.0, transparency, hlsl

Can **Silverlight** play **video with transparency**? 
 At least some tricky way for color keying with **C# or HLSL**? 
So if  you know any way how to please post some info.

**If yes.**
 What do I need?

- MSDN if there is any help on this.
- Open Source Libs/wrappers.
- Tutorials and blog articles on How to do it.

---

**If no**: I need know where did you get the information from (link to MSDN or other official Silverlight information resource).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with Silverlight 3 and pixel shares. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/synergist/archive/2009/05/14/alpha-video-with-silverlight-3-pixel-shaders.aspx) and [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SL3ChromaKeyEffect). Hope that helps. Can I ask what you're planing to do with it?

Comment: I plan on some tricky infinite multiple video layer loops) This filter from Shazzam Shader effects Samples might work to =)                            //________________________________ sampler2D implicitInputSampler : register(S0); //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- // Pixel Shader //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR { float4 color = tex2D( implicitInputSampler, uv ); if( color.r + color.g + color.b < 1.9 ) { color.rgba = 0; } return color; }